# Querying JIRA via REST API and possible bad values in query

Tags: python, rest, jira-rest-api, jql

I have a portal users can access built on cherrypy which has some forms which can be submitted that will be sent to JIRA via the REST api for tracking purposes. Once it has been submitted I then take the information from the user supplied information on the form and that JIRA Issue ID and send them to an oracle DB.

As well, I then extended the functionality of the portal to be able to view the user submissions via a list page and then select a record to view what is stored in the DB for that submission. I had the idea to then use the REST API for JIRA to get what the status and assignee is for the Issue within JIRA. Converting my code to submit to the API to instead query it with the necessary JQL statement was fairly simple and can be seen below.

```
def jira_status_check(jira_id):
if jira_id != "No JIRA Issue":
    try:
        search_url = "https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search/?jql=issue=" + jira_id + "&fields=status,assignee,resolution"
        print search_url
        username = 'some_user'
        password = 'some_password'
        request = urllib2.Request(search_url)
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        result = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        json_results = json.loads(result)
        print json_results
        jira_status = json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["status"]["name"]
        if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["resolution"] is None:
            tmp = "tmp"
        if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["resolution"] is not None:
            jira_status = jira_status + " - " + json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["resolution"]["name"]
        # assignee_name = "TEST"
        # assignee_NT = "TEST"
        if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"] is None:
            assignee_name = "Unassigned"
            assignee_NT = "Unassigned"
        if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"] is not None:
            assignee_name = json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"]
            assignee_NT = json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"]["name"]
        # if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"] is not None:
        #     assignee_name = json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"]["displayName"]
        # if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"] is None:
        #     assignee_NT = "Unassigned"
        # if json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"]["name"] is not None:
        #     assignee_NT = json_results["issues"][0]["fields"]["assignee"]["name"]
        print jira_status
        print assignee_name
        print assignee_NT
        output = [jira_status, assignee_name, assignee_NT]
    except:
        jira_status = "No JIRA Issue by that number or JIRA inaccessible"
        assignee_name = "No JIRA Issue by that number or JIRA inaccessible"
        assignee_NT = "No JIRA Issue by that number or JIRA inaccessible"
        output = [jira_status, assignee_name, assignee_NT]
else:
    jira_status = "No JIRA Issue"
    assignee_name = "No JIRA Issue"
    assignee_NT = "No JIRA Issue"
    output = [jira_status, assignee_name, assignee_NT]
return output
```

However it was limited to searching a single record at a time, which works when you are only viewing the single record, but I was hoping to extend this possibly to my list page and searching many at once with one api query rather than tons of single issue queries. I am capable of using jql and the rest API to search with multiple Issue numbers at a link like this `https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search/?jql=Issue%3DSPL-3284%20OR%20Issue%3DSPL-3285&fields=status,assignee,resolution`

But then I was thinking about what if somehow a bad Issue ID is saved and queried as a part of the massive query. Previously it was handled with the except statement in my `jira_status_check` function when it was a single record query. When I try to query the rest api with a link like the last one shared I instead get

```
 {"errorMessages":["An issue with key 'SPL-6666' does not exist for field 'Issue'."],"warningMessages":[]}
```

I tried to build a query from an advanced search of issues but when I do something like `Issue=SPL-3284 OR Issue=SPL-3285 OR Issue=SPL-6666` I get a response of `An issue with key 'SPL-6666' does not exist for field 'Issue'.`

Is there a correct way to search via JQL with multiple Issue numbers and give back no values for the fields for ones without matching issue numbers?

Or am I stuck with doing a ton of single issue queries to the api to cover my bases? This would be less than ideal, and might cause me to just limit the api queries to when a single record is viewed rather than the list page for usability.

Would I be better off moving my function to query JIRA to javascript/jquery that can populate the list of submissions after the page is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up reaching out to Atlassian with my question about JQL and then was given the following rest api documentation and told about the validateQuery parameter to add to my JQL to achieve my search. https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.1.7/

When I now use a query similar to this on my rest api link with my additional parameter

`jql=Issue%3DSPL-3284 OR Issue%3DSPL-3285&fields=status,assignee,resolution&validateQuery=true`

I get back a JSON with actual content for the issues which are valid and then a separate warningMessages object with any that are bad. An example JSON is below, but obviously $CONTENT would be actual results from the query

```
{
  "expand": "schema,names",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 2,
  "issues": [
    {
      $CONTENT
    },
    {
      $CONTENT
    }
  ],
  "warningMessages": [
    "An issue with key 'SPL-6666' does not exist for field 'Issue'."
  ]
}
```

Hopefully someone else will find this helpful in the future

Comment: Also note, this will not work as expected in a case of jql > PROJ-1234 . This query doesn't return any record if there is no PROJ-1234